# how to allow 3rd party to create repo (repo transfer) in our Org without let them see our private repo?

Tags: github, permissions, repository, external, transfer

We have hired a 3rd party to work on a project, we started by not creating any Repo on our Github, but they started with their Repo. So now it's time to transfer the repo. However, in order to transfer the repo, the developer is asking permission to create a Repo in our Org... but as far as I know, I can only invite him first as a collaborator, a member, before he can create any private repo in our Org... that means he can see our other repo...

I couldn't find any good answer online, please help. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using Github's Organization features? You can create an organization with your team members in it, and control who has access to what.

Here's a Github page that explains a bit [more](https://docs.github.com/en/github/setting-up-and-managing-organizations-and-teams/managing-an-individuals-access-to-an-organization-repository) about how it works.

Comment: I am using the Org, the paid version. the external developer needs to transfer his repo to our Org.

Comment: If he goes into his git repository settings, at the very bottom of the main page there's the option to transfer the repo to someone else. (Look in the "danger" section.)

Comment: Thanks Katrina, yes, he did that, but the thing is he is not in our Org. He cannot transfer the repo without the permission to create repo in our Org. I cannot give him access to our Org, because that will give him access to our existing private repo. I am stuck....

Comment: If you add him to the Org you should be able to set his access so he can't read or write to the private repo. That's the page I linked.

Comment: I have checked that answer... but there is no way I can manage the access of the user. because the user is not in my Org. If I add him, he will get access to all repos. 

but I have found a work around. Thanks Katrina

Comment: I'm glad you found something that worked! Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

Do not add them as a member to your Org! (this is the only option today from Github, nor owners...of course). If you do so, this will give your external developer access to all of your repos.

The only way I found you can safely invite an external user is to create a Repo first, then add them in that Repo. By doing that, they will be invited only to that repo, and have no access to the others.

This is my workaround. If you have a better solution, please do comment. I am curious how the "transfer" feature works.

[image]